# What are all of the pre-order specific technologies?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Per the [Photonix Core Wiki](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Photonix_Core) says , it says

> ... it is one of several technologies available only for pre-ordered players.

The Photonix Core was not mentioned as a bonus during the pre-order state. With that said, what are all of the pre-order specific technologies in *No Man's Sky*?

Comment: I'm confused about that wiki statement. I did not pre-order NMS, just ordered it on Amazon after release. And I certainly do have the Photonix Core on my ship. Not sure I installed it myself or got it when I found that ship.

Comment: Oh yeah, right, this is NOT a limited edition, just the standard PS4 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://gamepreorders.com/no-mans-sky), the **exclusive** items appear to be:

GameStop (physical, PS4):

> upgraded Alpha Vector ship

Steam / GOG / Humble Store (digital, PC):

> Horizon Omega ship equipped with an upgraded hyperdrive and increased firepower.

Limited edition PS4 version:

> Photonix Core (ship boost)

Comment: Are those ships unique in any way or are these just common ships with common configuration, just that you got em for free for pre-ordering?

Comment: @udondan I'm not entirely sure, I haven't seen any posts from people saying they found them on their own. At the very least, they're hard to come by.